# JSF Conversations ?cid - a right mess when someone bookmarks the page?

Tags: jsf-2, cdi, jboss7.x

Working in JBoss AS7, using Conversation Scope to manage the user's interactions within a browser tab.

I note that my pages get ?cid parameters appended. This is great - until the user bookmarks the page then tries to return to it! The Conversation Filter gives a "No such conversation" message.

Is there a better way of managing conversations? Perhaps an implementation or a switch to make it use hidden fields (with appropriate care in AJAX)? Alternatively I'll have to start trying to intercept the Conversation Exception or modify the filter!

Thanks
 - Richard

**Further:**

I'm intercepting the BeforeRestoreView event for other purpose (login handling mainly). You'd think this would work:

```
/**
 * @return true if there is no valid Conversation context.
 */
private boolean conversationNotActive()
{
    Context conversationContext = m_beanManager.getContext(ConversationScoped.class);
    return !conversationContext.isActive();
}
```

But I can't get the context to ask if if it's active! Will just throw a Try-Catch in for now.

Comment: This has solved it, but I'd still be interested to know if there's a better - less obtrusive (and less coupled to the container implementation) way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We now take a two pronged approach.

A quite complex conversation manager detects a bad conversation Id and takes appropriate action. It responds currently to the After Restore View event. I'd like to move it earlier but am having problems deriving the view ID at this stage. I've written a JSF to CDI bridge to pass the events to CDI. SeamFaces would do the same, but proved too heavyweight for us.

For a normal GET the Conversation Manager redirects to self without the cid parameter in order to cause a new conversation to be started. For a postback it returns an HTTP 410 error. The detection of dead conversation is as above. We could use a more random conversation Id when we create conversations to try to prevent collision if an ID is reused.

The Conversation Manager will also start a conversation depending on metadata it holds about the pages. (All pages under /forms/ require a conversation in our application). It uses redirect when it does this to ensure that the CID parameter is everywhere it needs to be. This may become unnecessary if I can solve the problem of getting the form ID before RestoreView phase.

We use the browser history API to remove the cid from the user's browser URL window.

Comment: Hi, could you please elaborate further on the solution you found for that problem, maybe some basic code?

Comment: I left that company over a year ago now, so no longer have access to the code. Sorry that the above is less helpful, as reading it now I'm not sure what I did.